# Why can Sitecore (V6.6) not send notifications for visitId from CD-server?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

In the Sitecore log on CD-server I found the following errors a lot:

```
ManagedPoolThread #98 10:03:56 ERROR Cannot send notifications for visitId: a425675d-2829-277b-300c-3882f33bb1c
Exception: System.ArgumentException
Message: The parameter 'address' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: address
Source: System
   at System.Net.Mail.MailAddress..ctor(String address, String displayName, Encoding displayNameEncoding)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.Actions.SendNotifications`1.SendMail(Subscription sessionSubscription, HtmlTextWriter output)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Rules.Actions.SendNotifications`1.Apply(T ruleContext)
```

The system is running on Sitecore version 6.6. Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure sender address for analytics emails.

Find the `Analytics.EMailFromAddress` configuration in your config files and set it to the proper value.

Comment: Email settings can be a bit confusing. See http://intothecore.cassidy.dk/2012/05/email-confusion-configuring-smtp.html

Comment: @MarkCassidy actually in 6.6 the code uses `Analytics.EMailFromAddress` config to generate `from` email address: `MailAddress from = new MailAddress(Settings.GetSetting("Analytics.EMailFromAddress"));`. Nevertheless, your article explains a lot and I'm sure you know much more about analytics than myself, so I won't argue here ;)

Comment: Is it possible to find out from which item the rule has been triggered (ItemId)? I changed Analytics loglevel to Debug, but I cannot find the itemId or how this rule has been triggered.

Comment: @Jordy to be honest, I have no idea. Your second question will get more attention if you ask it separately, instead of asking inside a comment.